# Should I put <?> for the generic type?

Tags: java

Consider this snipped code:

```
public class MaxSizeHandler extends AbstractValueHandler<Collection> {      
}
```

and I use eclipse, and It warns me to add infer generic arguments type for Collection and the code changes like this:

```
public class MaxSizeHandler extends AbstractValueHandler<Collection<?>> {       
}
```

My question is what's the problem if I don't put it, or what's the advantage if I put it?

Comment: Eclipse is asking - "A collection of What?."

Answer (score 5):

Passing a raw `Collection` will imply that the `Collection` is not parametrized, hence you lose the ability to strongly type (i.e. at compile time) what goes in the `Collection`.

Passing a `Collection<?>` is not substantially different, as the wildcard will match anything extending `Object`.

Of course, it will remove the warning.

The best way would be to pass a `Collection<MyObject>` or a `Collection<? extends MyObject>`, etc.

Comment: Great answer. Minor compile time benefits, major benefit in making Eclipse shut up. =)

Comment: @corsiKa another way of making eclipse shut up is not using eclipse ;)

Comment: The wildcard makes a big difference if you want to add items to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

you need to mention Collection type before itself in generic format like below :

```
public class MaxSizeHandler extends AbstractValueHandler<Collection<? extends T>> {      
}
```

T-> type of collections
Otherwise java compiler will take as default type of collection.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the correct type will allow the class to return the correct type of value, is there a specific type of Object your `Collection` will hold i.e `Integer`, then use `AbstractValueHandler<Collection<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you're using the `MaxSizeHandler` class it may make sense to make this class itself generic.  For example, if you need to iterate over the collection:

```
public class MaxSizeHandler<T>
       extends AbstractValueHandler<Collection<? extends T>> {
  public void handle(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
    for(T item : coll) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

or if you need to add new items to the collection:

```
public class MaxSizeHandler<T>
       extends AbstractValueHandler<Collection<? super T>> {
  public void handle(Collection<? super T> coll) {
    T item = createAnItem();
    coll.add(item);
  }
}
```

(These are just toy examples, as you haven't said what kind of methods `AbstractValueHandler` declares)